# How can I upload jar files with directory on JFROG?

Tags: java, artifactory

I would like to create local repository on Jfrog.
I have already created. But, want to upload files
I could download files with zip extension.
Howevet, i want to upload files like this way

com/xxx/bb/1.0.0/.jar like this way.

Thanks for helping..

Comment: artifactory rest api can be used. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Comment: i would like to add them all.. Thus, i used rest api's command already. I didnt make it :( It just works api that u meant as zip file or just a jar file..

Answer (score 1):

Using the JFrog CLI is probably your best option.
see here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles

Answer (score 0):

cli can be used but I wouldn't suggest to use it. REST api is the best way to upload artifacts. An example below on the usage would be.

> Deploy Artifact Description: Deploy an artifact to the specified
>   destination. Notes: You can also attach properties as part of
>   deploying artifacts. Security: Requires a user with 'deploy'
>   permissions (can be anonymous) Usage: PUT
>   /repo-key/path/to/artifact.ext Produces: application/json
>   (application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.storage.ItemCreated+json)

**Sample Usage:**

```
curl -X PUT -u <username>:<password> -T <artifact_name> "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/<repo_name>/<artifact_name>"
```

The above will upload to artifactory a single jar.

What is your use case for deploying jar/files ? Are the files part of the build process ? If yes it should be done using the plugin of artifactory for the respective CI tool.

For eg. if the CI tool is Jenkins than there is a plugin of aritfactory in jenkins that will upload post the build is success

Comment: My case is uploading jar files ex, org(file name) / apache(file name) / commons... 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/....jar like this.

Comment: You need to create a repository layout as per the above need then you can use the REST to deploy. REST will follow the convention of your repository layout